# How to merge pandas dataframes with different row and column sizes?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge dataframe 1 and dataframe 2 based on the 'Race's in dataframe2. I only want to include the 'Race's for dataframe 2 and do not want to include any the excess 'Race's from dataframe 1.

My code:

```
cols1 = ['Race', 'Market ID']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=betfairevents, columns=cols1)
cols2 = ['Race']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=tabntgevents, columns=cols2)
print(df2)
dfmerge1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Race',how='inner')
```

Output of dataframe1:

```
               Race    Market ID
0      Newcastle R1  1.171771969
1      Newcastle R2  1.171771971
2      Newcastle R3  1.171771973
3      Newcastle R4  1.171771975
4      Newcastle R5  1.171771977
..              ...          ...
139   Launceston R6  1.171772509
140   Launceston R7  1.171772511
141   Launceston R8  1.171772513
142   Launceston R9  1.171772515
143  Launceston R10  1.171772517
```

Output of dataframe2:

```
           Race
0  NEWCASTLE R1
1   BALLARAT R1
2    LISMORE R4
3   WARRAGUL R3
```

Desired output of merged dataframe:

```
               Race    Market ID
0      Newcastle R1  1.171771969
1      Ballarat R1   1.171771971
2      Lismore R4    1.171771973
3      Warragul R3   1.171771975
```

Comment: What is your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

You can use ".isin" function from pandas,

```
merged_df = df1[df1['Race'].isin(df2['Race'])
```

Answer (score -1):

The sample input data you're showing doesn't match the desired output.  But here is one way to perform the analysis:

```
# create sample data
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data1 = '''index               Race    Market ID
0      Newcastle R1  1.171771969
1      Newcastle R2  1.171771971
2      Newcastle R3  1.171771973
3      Newcastle R4  1.171771975
4      Newcastle R5  1.171771977
139   Launceston R6  1.171772509
140   Launceston R7  1.171772511
141   Launceston R8  1.171772513
142   Launceston R9  1.171772515
143  Launceston R10  1.171772517
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), sep='\s\s+', engine='python').set_index('index')

data2 = '''index           Race
0  NEWCASTLE R1
1   BALLARAT R1
2    LISMORE R4
3   WARRAGUL R3
'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2), sep='\s\s+', engine='python').set_index('index')
```

Now find 'Race' values that are in both df1 and df2 (with a boolean mask).  The `.str().lower()` performs case-insensitive comparison.

```
mask = df1['Race'].str.lower().isin(df2['Race'].str.lower().values)
df1[ mask ]
```

The `merge()` function would also work for this.

Comment: How does the sample data not match the output? There is no difference between the 'Race' columns for the two dataframes except for the capitalisation of the race names.

Comment: `'Cat' == 'cat'` will resolve to False, because python/pandas performs case-sensitive comparison.  Including `.str().lower()` will perform case-insensitive comparison.